# Add a file to existing changelist

Tags: perforce, changelist

I edited few files in my workspace and did `p4 change`. Then I remembered that I have to make some more edits to additional files(not in the changelist). I opened those files with `p4 edit` but how to add these files to existing changelist. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Since you use the command line, I'd be tempted to say that you `p4 help command` would show the help for the specified `command` right away.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In general you can use:

```
p4 reopen -c CLN FILE ...
```

to move open files into the specified changelist (regardless of whether they were open for edit, add, etc.).

`CLN` may be `default` to dissociate the specified files from any numbered changelist.

Comment: How moveout the file from Changelist

Comment: @AlokPrasad You can use `p4 reopen -c default FILE ...` to move the specified files out of a specific changelist and into the default, unnamed changelist.  I've updated my answer to mention that.

Comment: Maybe `p4` has changed since this answer was given, but I get `file(s) not opened on this client` when a file was not open. `p4 open` instead of `p4 reopen` works though.

Comment: @Enlico Correct, you would need to use `p4 open`/`p4 edit` for files not already open.  As I stated, you would use `p4 reopen` to move *open* files into the specified changelist, which is the scenario described by the original question.

Comment: @jamesdlin, oh, ok I had over-generalised your _regardless of whether they were open for edit, add, etc_. I thought it included also the _not open at all_ case.

Answer (score 13):

You can say:

```
p4 edit -c changelist# file ...
```

where `changelist#` refers to the pending changelist.

Comment: When I tried this I got: "can't change from default change - use 'reopen'"

Comment: @DarylSpitzer I have not used p4 in a long time but changing the accepted answer as per upvotes and your comment. I am sure at that time it worked for me.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam FYI, this answer works but only for files that are open for *edit*.  It won't work for files that were open for other actions.

Answer (score 1):

**file not open**

```
p4 edit -c [changelist] [file]
```

**file open already**

```
p4 reopen -c [changelist] [file]
```

**be lazy**

```
p4 edit [file] && p4 reopen -c [changelist] [file]
```

Answer (score 0):

p4 edit -c changelist file
same works for sd

Comment: Are you able to provide more information about this answer?

Comment: This works when opening the file for edit (same as @devnull's answer), and most other commands that open the file will accept a similar `-c change` option.  If you have already opened the file (for any arbitrary action) and want to put it in a different changelist after the fact you want to use the `reopen` command.